# MultiValueDictKeyError at /login/

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a customized signup and login form with sessions. The data is successfully saved in the db but when I'm trying to login into the system using email and password credentials. It is throwing an error. I'm unable to figure out the reason.

```
def user_login(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_email = request.POST['user_email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        member = authenticate(email=user_email, password=password)
        request.session['user_email'] = member
        if member:
            login(request, member)
            if request.GET.get('HomePage', None):
                return HttpResponseRedirect(request.GET['HomePage'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('success'))
        else:
            context["error"] = "Provide valid credentials !!"
            return render(request, "login.html", context)
    else:
        return render(request, "login.html", context)



def form_view(request):
    if request.session.in_key('user'):
        user = request.session['user']
        return render(request, 'HomePage.html', {"user": user})
    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html', {})


def logout(request):
    try:
        del request.session['user']
    except:
        pass
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('user_login'))
```

my signup form and login form

```
class UserSignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = "__all__"


class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = ['user_email', 'password']
```

urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('signup/', views.signup),
    path('login/', views.user_login, name="user_login"),
    path('success/', views.success, name="success"),
    path('logout/', views.user_logout),
    path('logout/', views.logout, name="logout"),
```

login.html file

```
 <form method="POST"  >
            {% csrf_token %}
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="user_email">Email</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Email" id="user_email" required></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="password">Password</label>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password" required></td>
                </tr>
                <p style="color: #9017ff;">{{error}}</p>
            </table>
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
```

homepage.html file

```
{% block content %}
    <p>User <b>{{user.username}}</b> is logged in successfully.</p>
    <form method="POST" action="/logout/">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" value="Logout">
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

model

```
class Users(models.Model):
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'user_email'
    user_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user_email = models.EmailField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    user_gender = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True,)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "Users"
```

Error:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /login/
    'user_email'
```

Expected result: Session should be created and user should be able to login into the system

Comment: Please show us the entire error, not just the error name.

Comment: There's *no point* in any of this; the user is already available via `request.user`. There's no reason to customise everything just so you already store the email in the session.

Comment: Note that "the entire error" means the __full__ traceback.

Comment: However the error itself is simply caused by the wrong `name` attribute on the HTML input element for the user_email.

Comment: Hint: use django forms.